# Capturar click en todo el Padre

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, typescript

Borro lo anterior...

A ver si consigo encontrar una solución, porque se vuelve a repetir en otro caso y no consigo encontrar una solución válida para ambos...

```
<ion-item (click)="selectContact($event)" class="contact-item" *ngFor="let contact of contactsFound">

  <h2>{{contact?.displayName}}</h2>

  <p *ngFor="let num of contact?.phoneNumbers">
    {{num.value}}
  </p>

</ion-item>
```

Lo que ocurre es que si hago click sobre cualquier parte del item... el evento click se captura correctamente pero...

Si desde angular pongo... `event.target.nodeValue` **NO** me devuelve el contenido... de donde haga click...

Si desde angular pongo... `event.target.firstChild.nodeValue`...

En caso de hacer el click sobre el `<h2>` obtengo el contenido del mismo...

En caso de hacer click sobre el `<p>` obtengo el contenido del mismo...

Mi intención es que independientemente del lugar en el que haga click en el interior del item obtenga el contenido del `<h2>`

O tambien, que al hacer click sobre cualquier parte del item, pueda acceder desde angular a traves de `event.target` al contenido de los dos hijos... ¿Como lo haría?

Es como si el evento click del `<ion-item>` se trasladara a los hijos y que al clickear sobre un hijo `event.target.childNodes.length` por ejemplo, devuelve en caso de hacer click sobre el `<h2>` -- 1, en caso de hacer click sobre la caja `<ion-item>` -- 2.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Ionic estas usando? He hecho una prueba y funciona correctamente hagas donde hagas click... ¿No muestra nada la consola al hacer click sobre la imagen o el texto?

Comment: Ionic CLI 4.12.0 - Angular CLI 7.3.7 -- Nada... ya funciona aunque de forma rara... el evento click si salta, el problema es que en el handleClick yo quiero recoger el ID de la ROW. Y si haces click sobre la imagen, esta no tiene ID asi que necesito obtener el ID del padre.

Comment: No me parece que estés usando el grind de ionic de la forma más correcta, pero igual debe funcionar, para obtener el valor correcto al hacer clic sugiero utilizar un ciclo y tomar los valores que irán en tu vista del código de tu componente <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items" class='answer' (click)="onClick($event, item.id)" align-items-center>
  <ion-col><img [src]="item.imagen" /></ion-col>
  <ion-col text-left>{{item.texto}}</ion-col>
</ion-row>

Comment: teoricamente el `event.target` es donde se genera el evento, osea si haces click en un h2 el evento nace en h2 y `event.target` seria h2, si le das a un P el `event.target` seria un P .. ecc,  en cambio si usas `this` va a ser siempre y en todo caso el elemento que tiene el `(click)` osea el listener del evento. nunca use Angular pero siendo un Framework basado En Javascript, deberia ser lo mismo ☺

Answer (score 1):

Aca te dejo lo que te comentaba, osea la diferencia entre `this` y `event.target` :

```js
var el = document.getElementById("diferencias");


el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.textContent + "  usando: event.target");
  console.log(this.textContent + "usando: this");
})
```

```html
<p>haz click en aqui abajo para apreciar la diferencia en la consola</p>
<br/>
<div id="diferencias">
<h2>{{contact?.displayName}}</h2>
<p>{{num.value}}</p>

</div>
```

si no tenes modo de usar el this podrias hacer algo equivalente que seria lo siguiente :

```js
var el = document.getElementById("diferencias");


el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.textContent + "  usando: event.target");
  console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent + "   usando: event.currentTarget");
  
  // en tu caso haria asi : 
  console.log(e.currentTarget.firstElementChild.textContent + "  solo el contenido del h2");
})
```

```html
<p>haz click en aqui abajo para apreciar la diferencia en la consola</p>
<br/>
<div id="diferencias">
  <h2>{{contact?.displayName}}</h2>
  <p>{{num.value}}</p>

</div>
```

osea usar `event.currentTarget` que seria equivalente al `this`

espero que te ayude a solucionar el problema, exitos !

Answer (score 1):

Trabajando con Angular/Ionic es mejor olvidarse del DOM y aprovechar la potencia de las plantillas: Pasa a la función lo que necesita directamente, haciendo algo como:

```
<ion-item (click)="selectContact(contact)" class="contact-item" *ngFor="let contact of contactsFound">

  <h2>{{contact?.displayName}}</h2>

  <p *ngFor="let num of contact?.phoneNumbers">
    {{num.value}}
  </p>

</ion-item>
```

De este modo tu compomente obtendrá sin complicaciones el contacto cuyo nombre está en el `<h2>`, sin tener que preocuparte por el evento o el DOM:

```
selectContact(contact) {
  // ...
}
```